# JS: How to turn this string into date object

Tags: javascript, date

The string is

```
2012-04-13T22:59:33
```

I have tried `Date.parse(str, "Y-m-dTH:i:s")` which doesn't work for me, I am not sure what does that "T" stands for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put it as a parameter to a date:

```
var date = new Date("2012-04-13T22:59:33");
```

If this doesn't work in older browsers, try:

```
var str = "2012-04-13T22:59:33",
    elems = str.split("T"),
    date = elems[0].split("-"),
    time = elems[1].split(":"),
    result = new Date(date[0],date[1]-1,date[2],time[0],time[1],time[2]);
```