# Go from ISODate to a nice formated string

Tags: javascript, date, type-conversion, isodate

In my application the dates are stored in ISODate format:

> ISODate("2012-04-21T07: 32: 16.285Z")

What would be the simplest wat to just have a string like this:

> 21/04/2012, 07:32:16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this script http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format

```
var d = new Date('2012-04-21T07: 32: 16.285Z'.split(' ').join('')), date;
date = d.format('d/m/Y h:i:s');
console.log(date);
```

**UPD:**
For IE < 9 you should normalize date - http://delete.me.uk/2005/03/iso8601.html

Comment: [That date constructor doesn't work in IE < 9.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10142754/1233508)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the zero padding, you can do this:

```
var d = new Date("2012-04-21T07:32:16.285Z");

var formattedDate = d.getUTCDate() + '/' 
    + (d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' 
    + d.getUTCFullYear() + ', ' 
    + d.getUTCHours() + ':' 
    + d.getUTCMinutes() + ':' 
    + d.getUTCSeconds();

// formattedDate is "21/4/2012, 7:32:16"
```

Otherwise you could do something like

```
// zero-pad a two digit integer
function zp(n) {
  return (n > 9 ? '' : '0') + n;
}

var d = new Date("2012-04-21T07:32:16.285Z");

var formattedDate = zp(d.getUTCDate()) + '/' 
    + zp(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' 
    + d.getUTCFullYear() + ', ' 
    + zp(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' 
    + zp(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' 
    + zp(d.getUTCSeconds());

// formattedDate is "21/04/2012, 07:32:16"
```

Comment: [That date constructor doesn't work in IE < 9.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10142754/1233508)

Comment: This is just an example. I assumed he already had date object, although I'm not clear on what `ISODate("2012-04-21T07: 32: 16.285Z")` is supposed to be (I figured a Date object, though).

Comment: Also, this input string is in the format recommended by W3C. The fact that IE does not support the recommended format just means they have a bug that needs to be fixed. Moz and Chrome have similar bugs. Best to avoid passing strings to Date altogether in production.